# Problems with custom config section

Tags: c#, app-config

I am trying to make a fairly simple custom configuration section.  My class is:

```
namespace NetCenterUserImport
{
    public class ExcludedUserList : ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("name")]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return (string)base["name"]; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("excludedUser")]
        public ExcludedUser ExcludedUser
        {
            get { return (ExcludedUser)base["excludedUser"]; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("excludedUsers")]
        public ExcludedUserCollection ExcludedUsers
        {
            get { return (ExcludedUserCollection)base["excludedUsers"]; }
        }
   }

   [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(ExcludedUser), AddItemName = "add")]
   public class ExcludedUserCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new ExcludedUserCollection();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((ExcludedUser)element).UserName;
        }
    }

    public class ExcludedUser : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("name")]
        public string UserName
        {
            get { return (string)this["name"]; }
            set { this["name"] = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

My app.config is:

```
  <excludedUserList name="test">
<excludedUser name="Hello" />
<excludedUsers>
  <add name="myUser" />
</excludedUsers>
```

When I attempt to get the custom config section using:

```
var excludedUsers = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("excludedUserList");
```

I get an exception saying

> "Unrecognized attribute 'name'."

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I've looked at a dozen examples and answers on here and can't seem to find where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Is `excludedUserList` the start of the section? If so, i dont think you can have an attribute attached to it.

Comment: Well not really - check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187523/adding-custom-attributes-to-custom-provider-configuration-section-in-app-config

Comment: Even without the attribute in excludedUserList I get the same error.  I only added to determine exactly when the error appeared.  I added a custom attribute to the section, then added the custom property to the sction and when those both worked, added the custom collection back in and everything broke again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ExcludedUserCollection.CreateNewElement method you are creating a ExcludedUserCollection instance, it should be a single element such as:

```
protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
{
    return new ExcludedUser();
}
```

Changing the method as above worked for me.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.  I knew it was something simple I was overlooking, but the only other developer in my office had a stroke, so I have no one to peer review things like this ATM.